# Query by a non-indexed (non-unique) PhoneNumber field to quickly find a customer

Tags: soql

I'm developing a webservice that recieves a phone number + country phone code and should return the customer (account) Id.
The phone number is not unique, and the webservice should return result in less than 10 sec.
I have the idea of creating a new field that creates a unique field by using the phone number, and I'm wondering if there is a better solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. This community is about providing answers to specific technical problems. It's hard to understand what do you exactly have a problem with. Please share what have you tried so far and where are you stuck at.

Comment: If the data content is not unique, creating a unique field will not help. What is the data volume in this object? Is the field custom or standard?

Comment: The field is standard, and the data volume is > 5M. thanks